# python hangman the counter variable is stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

The counter variable in file `hangman.py` line number 36
will not decrease after a wrong attempt.
It goes from 5 to 4 on the first attempt but after that for every wrong attempt it stays the same

[code for hangman](https://github.com/agentsam007/hangman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed your code in that repo and I think you're referring to [line 36](https://github.com/agentsam007/hangman/blob/master/hangman.py#L36) in the repo. That being said, python is not [pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). When you change `counter` inside the function `read`, you're not changing the global variable `lives`. If you run your program in interactive mode, `python -i prac.py`, then run `print(lives)` after you can see it's still at it's original value of 5. A work around to this could be to set the `global lives` in prac.py as follows:

```py
# original code:
    def func(par):
        x=par

        print(x)
        c1.create_text(100,0,fill='white',text=par)
        flag_3=ob1.read(x,lives)
```

```py
# new code:
def func(par):
    x=par

    print(x)
    c1.create_text(100,0,fill='white',text=par)
    global lives
    flag_3=ob1.read(x,lives)
    lives = flag_3
```

A more elegant solution however would probably be to have the `lives` variable as member of your `hangman` class.

Comment: i tried doing that but there was no change and flag_3 is used to check if the string entered is correct or not so the values of flag_3 will be 0 or 1

Comment: It works for me: https://imgur.com/a/2XaWOoS In the version of the code I used (hash 03788ba), your `read` function returns counter, which is simply the input arg counter decremented if the guess was incorrect.

Comment: As a side note, when trying to post to a forum about a bug, you want to make it a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example). This way people don't have to comb through a bunch of extra code that is unrelated to the issue. Most times you'll also find the bug when making the minimal example.